# validation triggered when click back button Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A user submits a form and all of the information is valid.

I just discoverd that when they click the back button the following validation gets triggered.

```
validates_format_of :email,
             :with => /^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i,
             :message => "should be something like youremail@something.com"
```

Why is this happening and how can I stop it from being triggered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the users re-submit the form - which the browser warns them about and which always happens when you go BACK to a POST-request in a browser - there is nothing you can do. It's how browsers work. Besides, just for clarity of language, it's not the "going back" that triggers a validation. It's the operation on the model you specified the validation for, probably before_save. So there is a model.save operation going on, and that's likely triggered (don't know YOUR code, you could write `@somemodel.save` anywhere in your controller, but it's standard) by that repeated POST operation. Which comes from the user, in the end. one should not go "back" to a form that was posted, it's the same all over the Internet regardless of backend technology.

Comment: Why? That would mean to stop people from going "back" whenever they want. Even now they are warned when they do: "Do you want to resubmit the form?" If they say "yes", why do you want to prevent it?

Comment: Actually, I think my answer is incomplete. It also depends on the headers with caching information, possibly, how the original form was sent. I just tried with my own pages and could go back and forth with no problems even after posting. This may be an issue especially/only with login - since you get a new session and the old one is invalidated.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175285/what-happens-when-i-press-browser-back-button
Different backend technology - does not matter, same browser issue.

Comment: Also see http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1f06a1af8a83f86f&hl=en
As I had said, a cache control issue, but maybe a better (longer) description there. This cache issue is mixed up with different behavior in various browsers - I hadn't known (or ever thought about) THAT. Thanks for bringing up something as an issue which I had learned to take for granted (and therefore never thought about) :)