# What's happening when the user clicks the "Back" button during a cookieless session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, architecture, cookieless

Can anyone explain to me what's happening when the user clicks the "Back" button during a cookieless session?

What I know about cookieless sessions is that in order to identify the session, the server will append the session ID to any link present in the response page.

So what will happen if the user doesn't click any link and instead presses the "Back" button?

Comment: Good to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175285/what-happens-when-i-press-browser-back-button

Answer (score 0):

One of three things:

- If the previous page was a form with a POST action, the session will be reset
- If the previous page had the session ID in the query string, the session will be maintained
- If the previous page did not have the session ID in the query string, the session will be maintained if you go forward again, or reset if it had a redirect or another URL with a different session ID in the query string is chosen

**References**

- [DuckDuckGo: Saving Settings](https://duck.co/help/settings/save)
- [Living without Sessions](http://www.peej.co.uk/articles/no-sessions.html)